# Multiple html form and submit

Tags: php, html

I'm wondering how to differentiate different submit and forms to a certain php function.

Currently I have 2 forms in my page, but each submit button will do 2 different thing.

I've tried using ISSET to control the submit but if failed, it always refer back to the same function.

Initially what I want to do is I wanna have the user to key in some verification info and submit the info to the database to do some checking (the data is in the database) and update the result on the same page, then only they proceed to submit the whole updated form to the payment gateway.

Comment: it differs on the form's attribute `action="mypage.php"`

Comment: you can differentiate by different name in submit button

Comment: @DrixsonOseña well that wouldn't be necessary

Comment: @NullPoiиteя just posted same answer

Comment: Can you use javascript/jquery? That should be fairly straight forward with it.

Comment: @NullPoiиteя, that was my first thought when he said 2 forms but upon seeing the answer below, you could be right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assign a name to your `submit` button like

```
<input type="submit" value="Update" name="first_form" />
<input type="submit" value="Update 2" name="second_form" />
```

So, now you can execute a particular code like

```
if(isset($_POST['first_form'])) {
   //Process first form
}

if(isset($_POST['second_form'])) {
   //Process Second Form
}
```

---

I just read your question again, not getting much, but it seems like you want to carry values to another form or you want to show forms only if the first form is completed, so the best way to do this is to have a `session` var, which will hold the users form data, so that you can carry it on another page, also you can set flags from which you can show particular data to the user, for example, if user completes form 1 set `$_SESSION['completion'] = 1` so you can use a condition to check whether session var isset, and if it is, whats the value and show the content to the user accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that PHP is a server side language, it only runs when the page loads.  If you want information on the screen to change without reloading the page, you will probably need to use Javascript or Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

if you use 2 form on basic html page, that wont do, because once it submitted, the page reloaded..
ajax is the aswers..

```
    var dataSet={ SERIALIZE_VALUE FROM FORM1 }; 
    $.post(URL_TO_PHP_ACTION_SCRIPT,dataSet,function(data){
        // check the return value here if its valid, then enable the 2nd form for submitting
     });
```

Comment: If I use ajax, will I able to get a value in return. Example if the form function returns a positive value, I can proceed with the php form submit that submits to the payment gateway

Comment: yep, just set a session or database in URL_TO_PHP_ACTION_SCRIPT and check the validity by the 2nd php script